# Android: is it possible to bend a view?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I would like to bend an image/view around cylinder form. This would require to somehow to transform view in 3d model and alter it to make a diferent shape.

Is this even possible in android?  If so, could the majority of devises be compatible with this feature?

Comment: Take a look at openGL, it is easy there!

Comment: Absolutely, OpenGL. Look around for examples or start with the docs (not trivial though). For instance: https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl